# parallel programs in Multi Core processors

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, multicore

Assume im trying to run parallel program with 3 different tasks on quad core processor
my question is ,when these tasks run simultaneously ,will they be computed on each core of processor
or in what way they are executed simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c# and parallel lib then yes, they would get queued up in the thread pool and executed in parallel, but there are few other factors that are very important to consider.
Such as:
- Is there is any shared data?
- Does one process need to wait on another?

Also order of execution is not guaranteed.